# coldfusion.security.NTAuthentication: Error in locating groups for user XXX in domain XXX

Tags: java, coldfusion, active-directory, ldap

I'm using `coldfusion.security.NTAuthentication` provided with ColdFusion to inteorrgate an active directory setup on a Windows SBS, with the intention of returning the groups a specific user belongs to.

On my development machine, this is working absolutely fine - however on the live machine I'm seeing the following error:

> Error in locating groups for user XXX in domain XXX.

The two machines *are* quite different, but not in any way that I think should matter.

Here's the set up:

**Dev machine**

- Windows 2008
- ColdFusion 11 Developer edition
- Java 8.0.25.18

**Production machine**

- Windows 2008 R2
- ColdFusion 10 Standard edition
- Java 8.0.710.15

**Active directory machine**

- Windows SBS 2011

It's worth noting that while these machines aren't identical, *both* are able to *authenticate* a user via the `authenticateUser()` method. 
This suggests that the class is functioning and able to connect to the AD server without problems.
I'm also able to use `<cfldap>` to retrieve information about a user.

Here's some very simple code:

```
Local.ntauth            = createObject("java", "coldfusion.security.NTAuthentication");
Local.ntauth.init('MyDomain');
Local.Authenticated     = Local.ntauth.authenticateUser('Username', 'Password'); // Returns 'YES'
Local.Groups            = Local.ntauth.GetUserGroups('Username') // Throws error
```

The issue isn't limited to the `GetUserGroups` method, a similar error occurs when attempting to use `IsUserInGroup`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using the same Active Dircetory from both environments?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Comment: I'm working on a theory that this is a bug in one of the CF hotfixes... I've got it working through a reinstall of ColdFusion, so just testing to see if I can replicate.

Comment: Nope... it's not a hotfix... it's Windows permissions!!  
I've narrowed it down to a call to the 'Samr' interface on the SBS server. It allows the NT Authority account, but denies access to the specific ColdFusion user I set up in production in the interests of locking down the server.... 
I'll update when/if I know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with Windows permissions. (Isn't everything?)

So, something I neglected to mention in the question is that the *production* server had been secured using the techniques detailed in the [CF10 Lockdown Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion-enterprise/pdf/cf10-lockdown-guide.pdf).

Part of this procedure involves creating a dedicated user for the ColdFusion service.

It seems that the `GetUserGroups` function worked if I used the standard '**Local System**' user, but not if I used my dedicated ColdFusion user.

With a bit of help from the Process Monitor, I noticed that when the `GetUserGroups` function is called, a call is made to the Active Directory server to `/PIPE/Samr`.

When ColdFusion is running with the **Local System** user, this call is made by **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** and returns a whole bunch of information - however when ColdFusion is running as the new dedicated user account, the call is made by that account and returns **LOGIN FAILED**.

Presumably there must be a way of granting the ColdFusion user, which is Local to the server, access to the Active Directory in such a way that a `GetUserGroups` call is allowed.

I'm not sure how to achieve that, so for now have reverted back to the **Local System**  user, but I may revisit this and update my answer.